# Cannot assign App\Entity\User to type Scheb\TwoFactorBundle\Model\Google\TwoFactorInterface

Tags: php, symfony

The exact error is

> Cannot assign App\Entity\User to property App\Controller\Admin\TwoFactorController::$twoFactorUser of type Scheb\TwoFactorBundle\Model\Google\TwoFactorInterface

I'm implementing Scheb's 2FA using it's example script at https://github.com/scheb/2fa/blob/7.x/app/src/Controller/QrCodeController.php

```
use Scheb\TwoFactorBundle\Model\Google\TwoFactorInterface as GoogleAuthenticatorTwoFactorInterface;

class TwoFactorController extends AbstractController
{
    private GoogleAuthenticatorTwoFactorInterface $twoFactorUser;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->twoFactorUser = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    }

    #[Route("/authentication/2fa/qr-code", name: "app_2fa_qr_code")]
    #[IsGranted("ROLE_USER")]
    public function displayGoogleAuthenticatorQrCodeSVG(GoogleAuthenticatorInterface $googleAutInterface): Response
    {
        $qrContent = $googleAutInterface->getQRContent($this->twoFactorUser);

        ...
     }
}
```

I tried with `$this->twoFactorUser = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();` and also since we're in AbstractController `$this->twoFactorUser = $this->getUser();`

The App\Entity\User is a standard Symfony Entity

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAut..
```

I also tried with phpdoc

```
/** @var \Scheb\TwoFactorBundle\Model\Google\TwoFactorInterface $user */
 $twoFactorUser = $this->getUser();
```

Nothing works.

The strange thing is, is that it works on my localhost.
PHPStan doesn't give any errors.
PhpStorm also doesn't give any errors.

Edit: Markdown code syntax

Edit : In reply to answer

```
public function isGoogleAuthenticatorEnabled(): bool
    {
        return (null !== $this->twoFactor_secret_google) and $this->isTwoFactorEnabled();
    }

    public function getGoogleAuthenticatorUsername(): string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getGoogleAuthenticatorSecret(): ?string
    {
        return $this->twoFactor_secret_google;
    }

    public function setGoogleAuthenticatorSecret(?string $googleAuthenticatorSecret): void
    {
        $this->twoFactor_secret_google = $googleAuthenticatorSecret;
    }
```

Comment: Is your `User` entity implements `Scheb\TwoFactorBundle\Model\Google\TwoFactorInterface`, see : https://symfony.com/bundles/SchebTwoFactorBundle/current/providers/google.html#basic-configuration

Comment: @Weenesta-MathieuDormeval yes, it implements UserInterface. And UserInterface extends \Scheb\TwoFactorBundle\Model\Google\TwoFactorInterface.